# Amazon MWS Orders API Timestamp Issue C#

Tags: c#, iso8601, amazon-mws

I am working on Amazon Marketplace Web Services Orders API. I recently downloaded MWS Orders API for C#. Amazon api require timestamps in ISO8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z').

```
request.CreatedAfter = new DateTime();
```

Here request.CreatedAfter is a datetime object. How can I set it to ISO8601 datetime?

Answer (score 2):

CreatedAfter is DateTime object, so can't use datetime string in it.

try to use something like this, let's say you need orders created in last 3 hours

> request.CreatedAfter = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-3);
>
> request.CreatedBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-2);

FYI:  you can't use DateTime.UtcNow in request.CreatedBefore. it should be at least 2 minutes before current time. you have to use UTC time.

Comment: The 2 minutes before is a well buried bit of knowledge, thanks for letting us know